# Создание таблиц или перенос базы

Tags: php

Добрый день! Вопрос: как лучше поступить: создавать таблицы в скрипте или переносить базу-"пустышку" на хостинг. Если создавать в скрипте, то нужно проверять на существование таблицу, а как?

Answer (score 1):

1) Самый простой способ - перенести пустую базу.
2) Написать SQL-запросы на создание/обновление и выполнять их вручную через PHPMyAdmin (обычно на большинстве php-хостингов он установлен).
3) Написать php-скрит, который будет автоматически выполнять SQL-запросы для обновления.

Проверить существование базы и/или таблиц можно введя в поисковике запрос **"Проверка MySQL на существование"** и др. Там сможете посмотреть множество решений, так как тема обсуждалась неоднократко.
Пример проверки существования/создания таблицы.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А если открыть phpmyadmin и нажать кнопку "экспорт"? Выгрузится дамп. В том же phpmyadmin на хостинге нажать "импорт". По-моему, самый простой способ.

Answer (score 0):

Переносите базу на хостинг. Либо сделайте отдельный файл, например, install.php который будет создавать все необходимые таблицы.